# Network Service Account folder permissioning issue

Tags: iis-7

We have server 2008 service pack 2 and IIS 7, currently we have an application that saves images to a folder and then transmits these images via http request. Occasionaly the network service account (account application is running under) will be unable to write to the folder. Even though the folder still indicates the the network service account has all neccessary permissions to do so. The only fix so far is to blow away the whole folder, re-make the folder and re-do the permissions. When I say redo the permissions i mean re-grant the network service full control.

Any ideas as to why this is would be very helpful. Thank you very much

Comment: Perhaps you should turn on audting on the server for that folder and see what shows.

Comment: You mention that your app is unable to write to the folder. Is there a stacktrace to go along with this? What exceptions/errors are you seeing?